# Drools multiple params in action sout

Tags: drools

I have the following code 
[(Here is the decision table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpYmY.png) and I need to put multiple params to console output. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *both* components change from row to row, it may be useful to have two action entries. If a constant should be appended, add it in the code snippet in line 3:

```
ACTION             ACTION
System.out         System.out
print($param)      println($param + "!")
part 1             part 2
"The city is: "    $city.getName()
"No such city"     ""
```

As an alternative, use

```
ACTION
System.out
println( $1 + ", " + $2 )
both names
$country.getName(),$city.getName()
```